# Replace specific values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I have next DataFrame in Pandas:**

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 10, 100], [2,2,200],[3,3,300], [4,40,400]],
                     columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Here it is:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   10  100
1   2   2   200
2   3   3   300
3   4   40  400
```

**What I want to do:** find rows, where `'A' == 'B'` and replace for this rows column `'C'` value.

So what I want to get:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   10  100
1   2   2   -1
2   3   3   -1
3   4   40  400
```

---

What I already tried:

```
data1[data1['A']==data1['B']]
```

So I find necessary rows. Now I try to replace values in this rows:

```
data1[data1['A']==data1['B']]['C'] = -1
```

But data1 is the same! Looks like this difficult chain indexing goes wrong or all this operation returns copy of dataframe. But I can't save it to new dataframe, because I used `=` in last command, I just can't write `newdf = data1[...] = -1`.
I found also `replace` function:

```
data1.replace(data1[data1['A']==data1['B']], "-1")
```

But it replace all values in row, when I need only last column:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   10  100
1   -1  -1  -1
2   -1  -1  -1
3   4   40  400
```

---

P.S. I know I can do it by using for loop. But I try to find better (more elegant) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use DataFrame.loc!

```
mask = data1['A'] == data1['B']
data1.loc[mask, 'C'] = -1
```

Comment: It works! The same solution as https://stackoverflow.com/a/49558169/4960953

Answer (score 1):

`df['C'] = np.where(df.A == df.B, -1, df.C)`

Comment: Are you sure it is correct answer? I tried it and get just last column (but yep with correct values).

Comment: You will need to reindex, e.g. `df['C'] = `

Comment: Can you please add an explanation? This by itself only helps the OP so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can using pandas `mask`

```
data1.C=data1.C.mask(data1.A==data1.B,-1)
data1
Out[371]: 
   A   B    C
0  1  10  100
1  2   2   -1
2  3   3   -1
3  4  40  400
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data1.loc[data1.A==data1.B,'C']='-1'
```

Comment: That works perfectly!